# Why constant voltage applied to pn-junction produces constant current throughout the junction?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, electric-current, voltage, semiconductor-physics, quantum-statistics

Is this assumption just something that turns out to be experimentally valid or there is at least some mathematical model like Kronig-Penney + some statistical mechanics that is able to give a good reason for that.

I'm more inclined to think such semiconductor models are increadibly complex and this just had to be an assumption, but maybe it is possible to describe this mathematically.

*Edit.* I know there are diodes that do not seem to obey this principle. So I'm interested in what are the exact assumptions for a "regular" pn-junction that allow this behaviour and why do they allow it (derived using some mathematical model)?

Comment: How is it different from constant voltage producing constant current through a resistor?

Comment: It makes little to no difference. However, resistors are way simpler and Drude model seems   intuitive to me. Not the case with all the complex quantum mechanics involved in semiconductors. Also, a good answer for a diode will likely give me some insight on the resistor case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**p-n junction is not a generator**

> Why constant voltage produces constant current throughout the pn-junction?

It would be rather unexpected, if it were not the case. E.g., if in response to a constant voltage p-n junction produced an oscillating current, it would mean some kind of internal oscillations being generated. A p-n junction is too simple a structure to sustain such oscillations, although a bit more complex circuits made of transistors (which are usually p-n-p or n-p-n junctions) do serve as generators of oscillations.

**Current-voltage characteristics**
What makes p-n junction different from a resistor is not the time-dependence of the current, but the *current-voltage characteristics*, that is how the current changes with voltage. While for a resistor it is simply proportional to voltage
$$
I = \frac{V}{R}
$$
in a p-n junction this behavior is more complex, e.g.,
$$
I=I_0\left(e^{\frac{V}{V_0}}-1\right),
$$
which means that the current is very small for the reverse bias ($V<0$) - approximately $-I_0$, but it very quickly grows for a positive bias ($V>0$).

[image]
([image source](https://www.savemyexams.co.uk/as/physics/cie/19/revision-notes/11-current-of-electricity/11-2-resistance--resistivity/11-2-3-i-v-characteristics/))

**Non-linear elements**
Some semiconductor devices, like those mentioned in the answer by @JohnDoty, are explicitly designed to have more complex current-voltage characteristics, where more than one value of current may correspond to the same value of voltage (a kind of hysteresis). This however usually happens not for constant bias, but in ac regime.

Comment: I meant external voltage source. I already fixed that, sorry

Comment: @Sigg8 it is understood that it is external voltage source. What kind of behavior did you expect from a p-n junction?

Comment: possibly time-dependent

Comment: If voltage is time-dependent, then the current would be time dependent as well. But since now it is not anymore proportional to the voltage, there will be more current for the positive voltage and less for the negative. This is why p-n junctions used for filtering ac current. See, e.g., [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode#Applications) I suggest that you do some introductory reading, [like this](http://britneyspears.ac/physics/pn/pnjunct.htm)  or even something simpler - you mix several rather remotely related things in your question.

Comment: I was talking specifically about constant voltage.

Comment: @Sgg8 that would be highly unusual behavior for most materials. Perhaps, with exception of quartz crystals.

Answer (score 1):

Rectifier diodes are designed to have tame behavior. There are diodes that are not so tame, [Gunn diodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gunn_diode), [tunnel diodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunnel_diode), ...

Edit:

Nature gives us phenomena, not axioms. The math is extracted from the phenomena. Phenomena are not derived from the math. The math is a story crafted to match the phenomena it addresses. For the case of a rectifier diode, we have the [Shockley equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shockley_diode_equation).

Comment: Yes! This emphasises the significance of my question. And shows that I need to specify it a little bit. I'm interested in what are the exact assumptions for a "regular" pn-junction that allow this behaviour and why do they allow it